# POST AJAX DJANGO 403 forbbiden after adding csrf token

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, angularjs, post

I am trying to do an ajax post to my django's backend and I am getting "error 403, forbbiden", using AngularJS as front-end.

I know that I have to send through my post data the csrf token, but my django view is not detecting it.

I had tried everything, since using the '{%csrf_token%}' in my forms, {{csrf_token}} in my ajax data and I still get the same error.

View.py

`from django.views.decorators.csrf import *`

```
def getCookie(request):
   if request.method == 'GET':
       data = django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)
       return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

@csrf_protect
def guardarGrupo(request):
   var = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
     if request.is_ajax() and request.method=='POST':    
      return HttpResponse(var)
```

`

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^grupo/guardarGrupo/$', views.guardarGrupo, name='GuardarGrupo'),
  url(r'^getCookie/$', views.getCookie, name='getCookie'),  
  ...
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
...
```

JS file

```
 var token;
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getCookie/', function(json) {
        console.log("getjson:"+json);
        token = json;
    }).done(function() {
        console.log("token:"+token );
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/grupo/guardarGrupo/',
            data: {valor: 'hola',csrfmiddlewaretoken : token},
            success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
            error: function (error) { alert(token);},
        });

    });
```

angularjs (config)

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
// these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
angular.module('dService', [])
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider, $http) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }
]);
```

Both console.log prints the same. But, my django view isn't returning.
I appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you dont see any console log errors?

Comment: @karthikr Yes, I checked the console.log on chrome and in the form data says: valor:'something', csrfmiddlewaretoken: 'Qgdxhxh243 ...'. That's why I don't understand why Django is returning 403. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For each XHR requests you'll make you'll have to add a header called X-CSRFToken header with the value of the CSRF token.

Note that by default, with the CSRF protection on, Django **will always send the cookie called csrf on the first GET request** (no csrf protection required). 
So you don't need an endpoint that will give you the token.

You have to read the token which is stored in the csrf cookie. You can use [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) to access the cookie, grab the token and add it to each request made by your module.
This is how I manage the CSRF :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mymodule', [
    'ngCookies',
    //...
    ])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])
    .run(function($http, $cookies) {
        $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
    })
```

This will be enough to protect all your endpoints with CSRF
in your settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

Btw, now that you have AngularJs running forget about doing your requests with JQuery. Have a look at [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) if your planning on building a RESTful API.

**The jQuery Method :**
If you prefer using jQuery rather than Angular, this post will show you to do it [django 403 error on ajax view with csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496751/django-403-error-on-ajax-view-with-csrf-token?rq=1)

hope this helps

Comment: Oohh...It didn't work :( thank you btw. I still get 403 Forbbiden

Comment: Could you provide the code you're are using to make the request. I guess in your angular controllers. You should try sending request with Postman which is a chrome app

Comment: Okay, Angular is not needed here in this case. If you are doing your requests with jQuery you don't need Angular. I have added the jQuery method to my answer which works fine

Comment: Tried that, still not working, getCookie() returns null. I got a token only using  django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request), but still getting 403

Comment: u may try to delete the cookies, it might be causing problem.